# Mounted HDD not having enough permissions from Apache/PHP

Tags: php, linux, apache-http-server, mount

Piwigo gallery, on apache and php.

The root system is a RAID 128GB. /var/www/html is on the root file system.

Mounted the 320GB hdd to /var/www/html/320 using defaults, it's an ext4 fs.

Put a symlink to it in /var/www/html/galleries which is read by the gallery script so I can upload images to there, then click sync. It gives me the error:

[./galleries/] PWG-ERROR-NO-FS (File/directory read error)
PWG-ERROR-NO-FS: The file or directory cannot be accessed (either it does not exist or the access is denied)

chmod 777 set on /dev/sdb1, /var/www/html, and /var/www/html/320 as well as the symlink galleries too. All recursive.

chown apache:apache to everything too.

PHP just can't read/write to it. I tried with and without the symlink, I've tried everything I can think of. Nothing.

Any ideas how I can give apache/php permission to read/write to this drive? With 777 permissions all around it should already be able to.

Comment: do **NOT** change perms on devices in `/dev` unless you know what you're doing. You've now granted ALL users of your system access to the raw bytes of the drive, allowing them to suck out (or spit in) ANY data they want on the drive.

Comment: I can change it right back, was just a trial to get it working. The entire drive is dedicated to just that directory for storing photos.

Comment: i would suggest asking in: http://serverfault.com/

Answer (score 0):

sometimes, depending on Apache's configuration, it's set not to be able to read or write outside its doc-root. It is also possible that it is configured not to follow symlinks (which is done at vhost level).

¿Why don't you mount the new hdd in /var/www/html/galleries directly?

Otherwise, instead of symlinks, try using a bind mount:

```
mount --bind /var/www/html/320 /var/www/html/galleries
```

I'm assuming you had no problems accesing /var/www/html/320 from the command line

Comment: I tried directly without the link and then read that the link would help. I'll remove it and try the bind right now. I'll post an update in a couple of minutes. Thanks

Comment: Still has the same error. I've since tried making apache run under my own account, and also specified the directories in httpd.conf. I've made sure FollowSymLinks is set on everything too.

Comment: it's now mounted directly to the galleries directory. I've since set apache back to run as apache again too. I'm very confused here. I just can't figure out why it doesn't have permission to read when I'm connected to it now uploading files and folders to the drive to be synced.

Comment: Please do a df -h in terminal and put the output please :)

Comment: I was looking at [Piwigo source code](http://www.phpkode.com/source/p/piwigo/piwigo/admin/site_update.php)  and it seems that the ```PWG-ERROR-NO-FS``` error message can be triggered if it can't find some files in the galleries (see line 765). Maybe it's just a poorly described exception and has nothing to do with hdd permissions?

Comment: I assume that it can't find them due to permissions. If I copy all contents from the 320 hdd, back onto the main hdd and into a simple directory called galleries, it works perfectly. However I don't have the space. The file structure is identical when using the mounted hdd. Even the links work and everything. It just won't sync and I don't know why.

Comment: Do you have GD2 library already loaded? check if that works

Comment: `Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/vg_daryl-lv_root
                       50G  2.9G   46G   6% /
tmpfs                 2.0G   72K  2.0G   1% /dev/shm
/dev/sda1             485M   66M  395M  15% /boot
/dev/mapper/vg_daryl-lv_home
                      176G  252M  167G   1% /home
/dev/sdb1             294G   52G  227G  19% /var/www/html/galleries`

Comment: GD is installed and works fine if it's using the galleries directly on the main hdd and not the mounted one.

Comment: read this thread i found maybe here is the solution you need http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19598201/umounting-through-exec-with-sudo-the-user-is-a-sudoer-with-nopasswd/19682810#19682810, i think here you need to read some more about system namespaces :)

Comment: That looks interesting. So Apache may somehow not be able to read or get the actual filenames or locations properly? How can I fix it? That links looks pretty complex. Can you suggest what to change and where?

Comment: I don't have a /etc/systemd

Answer (score -1):

Fixed.

Edit /etc/selinux/config and change it to disabled, then reboot the machine. Works now.

Comment: What did you change to disabled? Please be more specific.